# Is it possible to exclude some targets from Ant targets while executing the script?

Tags: java, ant

In ant if want to execute more than one target, we can do it like this,

```
ant target1 target2 target3
```

Other way could be, create target4 like

```
<target name="target4" depends="target1,target2,target3" />
```

but the problem is, one of my target definition is:

```
<target name="buildApp" depends="init,copy-all-requiredfiles-local,wait-to-merge,compile,createWAR,deployAll"/>
```

and if i want to execute *buildApp* then it will run all associated targets too, as obvious.
Is it possible to execute the *buildApp* target without executing *deployAll* target?

Comment: Your targets and dependencies are interesting. I would think deployAll has a dependency on buildApp and not the other way round.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A possibility would be add a condition to your *deployAll* target like this.

```
<target name="depolyAll" unless="doNotDeploy">
...
</target>
```

Then when you want to run *buildApp* without *deployAll* on the commandline just do

```
ant -DdoNotDeploy=true buildAll
```

btw. note that unless just checks if the property is set. Not what the value is.

But this behaviour should be documented and is a little obscure.

I would consider explicitly creating a second build target e.g. *buildAllWithoutDeploy* which just misses the deploy target

Answer (score 2):

Why not create another target for it?

```
<target name="buildAppNoDeploy" depends="init,copy-all-requiredfiles-local,wait-to-merge,compile,createWAR"/>
```

Comment: certainly i can create another target, but i was not expecting this. :)